When is an $R$-bilinear map over a commutative ring $R$ (without identity) also $R$-balanced?
Dummit & Foote in their Abstract Algebra text defines the notion of an $R$-bilinear map (on pg. 368):

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$ and let $M, N$, and $L$ be left $R$-modules. The map $f:M\times N\to L$ is called $R$-bilinear iff it is $R$-linear in each factor

and also the notion of an $R$-balanced map (on pg. 365):

Let $M$ be a right $R$-module, $N$ be a left $R$-module and $L$ be an abelian group. A map $f:M\times N\to L$ is called $R$-balanced iff: (i) $f(m+m',n)=f(m,n)+f(m',n),\ $ (ii) $f(m,n+n')=f(m,n)+f(m,n'),\ $ and (iii) $f(mr,n) = f(m,rn)$.

Then in Corollary 12 (Sec. 10.4, pg. 368) they prove the analogue of the Universal Property for $M\otimes_R N$ when $M$ is an $(R,R)$-bimodule, $N$ is a left $R$-module and $R$ is any commutative ring. My problem is with this assumption that "$R$ is a commutative ring" instead of "$R$ is a commutative ring with identity". This is because in the proof, they claim "any $R$-bilinear map $M\times N\to L$ is also $R$-balanced." I'm convinced that $R$-bilinearity implies $R$-balancing when $1\in R$ though. But I don't see how this is the case if $R$ does not have an identity. Is this a typo in the book, or am I missing something here? How are conditions (i)&(ii) satisfied if $1\not\in R$ ?? TIA.

In that section of the book, any ring is supposed to have an identity.
However, the definitions of bilinear and balanced map makes perfect sense for rings without an identity:

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, and let $M,N$ and $L$ be left $R$-modules. A map $f \colon M \times N \to L$ is called $R$-bilinear if

$f(m_1+m_2,n) = f(m_1,n)+f(m_2,n)$ for all $m_1,m_2 \in M$ and $n \in N$;
$f(rm,n) = rf(m,n)$ for all $m \in M$, $n \in N$ and $r \in R$;
$f(m,n_1+n_2) = f(m,n_1)+f(m,n_2)$ for all $m \in M$ and $n_1,n_2 \in N$;
$f(m,rn) = rf(m,n)$ for all $m \in M$, $n \in N$ and $r \in R$.

The first two dots means that, for each $n \in N$, the map $f(\_,n) \colon M \to L$ is $R$-linear; and the last two dots means that, for each $m \in M$, the map $f(m,\_) \colon N \to L$ is $R$-linear.
That's the reason of the name.

Let $R$ be a ring, let $M$ be a right $R$-module, let $N$ be a left $R$-module, and let $L$ be an additive abelian group.
A map $f \colon M \times N \to L$ is called $R$-balanced if

$f(m_1+m_2,n) = f(m_1,n)+f(m_2,n)$ for all $m_1,m_2 \in M$ and $n \in N$;
$f(m,n_1+n_2) = f(m,n_1)+f(m,n_2)$ for all $m \in M$ and $n_1,n_2 \in N$;
$f(mr,n) = f(m,rn)$ for all $m \in M$, $n \in N$ and $r \in R$.



Hence, if $R$ is a commutative ring and $f \colon M \times N \to L$ is an $R$-bilinear map ($M,N$ and $L$ are left $R$-modules), then $f$ is $R$-balanced just because
$$
f(mr,n) = f(rm,n) = rf(m,n) = f(m,rn)
$$
for all $m \in M$, $n \in N$ and $r \in R$.
(Here we are seeing $M$ as a right $R$-module in the canonical way: $mr:=rm$ for all $m \in M$ and $r \in R$.)

You answer does make sense. I have two follow-ups: (1) So I should think of Corollary 12 as a result for $R$ a commutative ring with $1$ and the modules are all unital? (2) Your definition above for an $R$-bilinear map got me thinking if this is how we must define such maps for a commutative ring without $1$ ? .......

........ (continued) I say that because if $1\in R$ then we can just write the conditions on each entry in the form $f(rm+r'm',n) = rf(m,n) + r'f(m',n)$. But if $1\not\in R$ then we must write out the four conditions separately. Just want to confirm if I'm understanding these subtle differences correctly.

(1) Yes. In that section, it is implicitly assumed that all rings have an identity. (2) Yes. The two conditions $g(x_1+x_2)=g(x_1)+g(x_2)$ and $g(rx)=rg(x)$ of the definition of $R$-linear map are equivalent to the single condition $g(r_1x_1+r_2x_2) = r_1g(x_1)+r_2g(x_2)$ only when the ring has an identity.

Thanks for confirming. This was helpful.
